# Building ceres-solver for ios with multithreading support

Tags: ios, multithreading, cmake, ceres-solver

Hello I am trying to build [ceres](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver) for ios from [here](http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html)

I can build fine with the recommended build settings but it builds without multithreading.

I would like to add multi-threading support. Is there any way to add multi-threading support with `OpenMP`, `TBB` or `C++`?

Comment: what version of Ceres are you trying to build?

Comment: ceres-solver-1.14.0